# ReportViewer in 2012 won't bind to SQL Server Compact datasource

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-ce, ssrs-2008, sql-server-ce-4

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Compact 4.0. When I try to bind the ReportViewer control to an instance of a datasource via the designer, it won't bind (the selectable instance is disabled)

The error message is :

> *An error occurred during local report processing.
>
>   The report definition for report 'Report1' has not been specified
>
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Would it be possible to do this is the code behind? A few attempts resulted in similar binding errors.

Has anyone managed to get reporting working with SQL Server Compact 4.0? In VS2010, it works with SQL Server Compact 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC? If so, check the post at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/39cf2d43-7fc6-474f-bcbf-72e416bca7fd. This may be a known limitation.